# Nginx limit requests by parameter in body or query?

Tags: http, nginx, proxy, limit

I need to limit (GET,POST) requests with specific parameter containing in body or query parameters. How to configure NGINX for that?

Current nginx config:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:10m rate=10r/s;
server {
    listen       8044;
    limit_req_log_level warn;
    location /route/{
       limit_req zone=mylimit burst=1000;
       proxy_pass https://the_Cool_server/;
 }}
```

For example- the request like:

`http://localhost:8044/route/path1/path2?param1=param1VALUE_to_limit1&param2VALUEAWESOME`

I need the NGINX to limit requests with param1 value per second. So, every request with same param1 should be limited to 10 per second.

Maybe i should use openresty for it?

Comment: Examples of what you want to do would be great

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72516213/rewrite-wordpress-search-url-from-s-to-search-with-nginx

Answer (score 2):

**limit_req** parameter can be inside **http**, **server** or **location** block, so traditionally you can only limit requests by **path**, like:

> http://localhost:8044/route/path1/path2

but, there is a workaround to map visitor ip to variable only if he hits your query string key (param1), then use that var ($do_limit) in **limit_req** directive, like:

```
map $arg_ctl    $do_limit {
    "param1"    $binary_remote_addr;
    default     "";
}
limit_req_zone $do_limit zone=mylimit:10m rate=10r/s;
server {
    listen       8044;
    limit_req_log_level warn;
    location /route/{
       limit_req zone=mylimit burst=1000;
       proxy_pass https://the_Cool_server/;
 }}
```