# How to set rate limit for specific queries in php with nginx

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-18.04

I have a php file called **"sample.php"**.

This file contains query_string in several different ways. Some innocent users use these query_strings at maybe 100 requests per minute (no problem).

However, some query_strings are used at most 2-3 times a minute and there is no need for more. Bruteforce or ddos requests also come from here.

I can set "sample.php" to 4 requests per minute with the nginx rate limit, but this sometimes causes innocent users to be blocked. I want to be able to set a rate limit for certain query_strings, but I couldn't find a precise way to do this.

**For example:**

*/sample.php?type=stb&action=handshake&token=*

or

*/sample.php?action=handshake&type=stb&token=&mac=**(random_string)***

I want to put rate_limit on such requests but I don't know the way. (I'm not talking about putting rate_limit entirely in sample.php)

Is there someone who can help? Thank you.

edit:

```
location ~* /sample.php(*mac\=*)
```

If i find to write a good regex like above i can fix but i am not good at regex.

I need to rate limit only : sample.php?(whatever)?mac=(whatever) url's.

Comment: Are your users logged in? If so, you could implement a per-user limit for whatever kind of query you wish.

Comment: If youre having issues with ddos attacks, then you should probably look into ddos protection software. Also: how often does your data change? Maybe caching would help here?

Comment: List changing always daily. Caching.. A clue?

Comment: sample.php is encrypted. And works non-logged-in users also. Unfortunately I can not revert it.

Comment: if query_string = type=stb&action=handshake&token= 
if query_string = action=handshake&type=stb&token=&mac=(random_string) 

then 

.
.
: rate limiting 4r/m 

All i want to do this. But couldnt ...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46178259/nginx-limit-requests-by-parameter-in-body-or-query

Answer (score 0):

You may use redis for easily saving info about amount of queries in time duration. If you'd have login system, you can do it per user, if not - for IP or token which you can generate previousily.
In redis you may set timeout for key: https://redis.io/commands/expire. Or in another db or even file.

Comment: That not solved my problem. 

I only need to rate limit if reques_uri is like : sample.php?mac=xx.xx.xx (and not rate limit all other versions of sample.php )