# Rewrite WordPress search URL from "/?s=" to "/search/" with Nginx?

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I want to rewrite the WordPress default search URL slug to clean the URL. For an instance default URL slug is `https://example.com/?s=` but I want to replace it with `https://example.com/search/`

I use the following code inside the `server{` block. But it seems it is not working.

> if ($query_string ~ "\?s=([^&]+)") { rewrite ^/$ /search/%1/? last; }

How do I do it with Nginx?

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @dvaer on WordPress.org:

```
server {
    # ... other server configuration ...

    location / {
        # ... other location settings ...

        if ($args ~ "^s=(.*)$") {
            set $search_query $1;
            rewrite ^ /search/$search_query? permanent;
        }
    }

    location /search/ {
        # ... other location settings ...

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # ... other server configuration ...
}
```

He notes the following:

> Explanation:
>
> 1. In the location / block, you use an if condition to capture the search query parameter using a regular expression match on the $args
>    variable. If the condition is met, the search query is stored in the
>    $search_query variable.
> 2. You then use the rewrite directive to perform a permanent (301) redirect to the desired /search/text format, where $search_query is
>    the captured query parameter.
> 3. In the location /search/ block, you use the try_files directive to handle requests for the rewritten URLs. This will try to find a
>    matching file, and if not found, will pass the request to WordPress’s
>    index.php along with the query string.
>
> Please make sure to replace the comments like `# ... other server configuration ...` with your actual server and location block
> settings. Also, be cautious when using `if` directives in Nginx, as
> they can have performance implications if not used carefully. In this
> case, the `if` directive is used to handle the search query parameter
> rewriting and should work as intended.

Ref: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/nginx-redirect-for-search-pages/

Comment: I'm also curious to explore rate-limiting opportunities with this approach, that are not otherwise supported in Nginx with query strings...

Comment: Related: https://slickstack.io/forum/topic/would-rewriting-wp-search-url-to-search-help-with-rate-limiting-requests